# Svg Inline Loader & Vue 3 only displayed text

Tags: vue.js, svg

I tried to use svg-inline-loader in order to display easily svg and access to color property, etc...

```
<template>
  <div
    :class="[`svg-${name}`, 'v-svg']"
    :style="{ height: h }"
    v-html="require(`!svg-inline-loader?classPrefix=true&idPrefix=true!@/assets/svg/${props.name}.svg`)"
  />
</template>
```

I think i got the good syntax but when I use it, the component display only something like **/img/chat.e0af9c58.svg** and do not display the right svg.

Did someone have an idea ?

Thank you all !